# Geonode paver setup not setting geonode correctly

Tags: python, django, gis

i am installing geonode, when i came across the instruction of paver setup. It is not running properly. The error message given as shown below.

```
(geonode) eidul@eidul-Virtual-Machine:/opt/geonode$ paver setup
free(): invalid pointer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eidul/.virtualenvs/geonode/bin/paver", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/eidul/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 890, in main
    _launch_pavement(args)
  File "/home/eidul/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 858, in _launch_pavement
    exec(compile(source, environment.pavement_file, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
  File "pavement.py", line 62, in <module>
    from geonode.settings import (
  File "/opt/geonode/geonode/settings.py", line 115, in <module>
    spatialite_version = int(spatialite_proc.stdout.decode()[0])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

**spatialite** is no longer supported. Please use Postgres with Postgis enabled

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Mattia **spatialite** is no longer supported.
If you already have configured postgres with postgis and still getting the error. you can change the **settings.py** as follows (not a recommended way)

Change this section and add your **DATABASE_URL**

```
# add trailing slash to site url. geoserver url will be relative to this
if not SITEURL.endswith('/'):
SITEURL = f'{SITEURL}/'

_DB_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'development.db')

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv(
'DATABASE_URL')

#if DATABASE_URL.startswith("spatialite"):
#try:
#spatialite_proc = subprocess.run(["spatialite", "-version"],     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#spatialite_version = int(spatialite_proc.stdout.decode()[0]) 
#if spatialite_version < 5:
        # To workaround Shapely/Spatialite interaction bug for Spatialite < 5
#        from shapely import speedups
#       speedups.enable()
#except FileNotFoundError as ex:
#   print(ex)

# DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://test_geonode:test_geonode@localhost:5432/geonode'

DATABASE_URL='postgis://geonode:geonode@localhost:5432/geonode'
```

Recommended is to use your own settings file.